# Как я могу наиболее правильно задать на Kotlin один конструктор без параметров и один конструктор с n параметрами?

Tags: java, android, классы, kotlin, конструктор

Пример на Java - имеется класс MessageEvent c какими-то полями, не суть важно, пусть будет:

```
public String key;
public User user;
private int pos;
```

Я делаю два конструктора

```
public MessageEvent(User user, String key) {
        this.user = user;
        this.key=key;
    }

public MessageEvent(User user,String key,int pos){ 
        this.user=user;
        this.key=key;
        this.pos=pos;
    }
```

Хочу из других классов иметь возможность вызывать разные конструкторы и таким образом задавать разную конфигурацию класса MessageEvent.
Каким образом наиболее верно это будет выглядеть на Kotlin?Пихать null в те параметры которые не использую выглядит костыльно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здесь есть `primary constructor` который принимает все аргументы. И есть `secondary constructor`, который принимает только 2 аргумента.

```
class MessageEvent(
    val user: User,
    val key: String,
    val pos: Int?
) {

    constructor(user: User, key: String) : this(user, key, null)
}
```

Либо еще проще:

```
class MessageEvent(
    val user: User,
    val key: String,
    val pos: Int? = null // можно к примеру и так записать, если не хотите работать с null 'val pos: Int = 0'
)
```

Тогда вы можете задавать только 2 параметра, а третий по дефолту будет `null`, или же все три параметра вместе с `pos`.

В целом используя второй вариант вы можете задавать любое количество дефолтных параметров (паттерн Builder).

**UPD.** С пустым конструктором:

```
class MessageEvent(
        val user: User? = null,
        val key: String? = null,
        val pos: Int? = null
    )
```

Простой вариант.

Можете сделать что-то вроде такого:

```
class MessageEvent() {
        var user: User? = null,
        var key: String? = null,
        var pos: Int? = null
    
        constructor(user: User, key: String, pos: Int) : this() {
            this.user = user,
            this.key = key,
            this.pos = pos
        }
    }
```

[Статья на тему конструкторов.](https://habr.com/ru/company/funcorp/blog/425943/)

Comment: Я хочу иметь пустой конструктор, в котором буду делать то, что захочу с переменной класса. То есть ничего не передавать конструктору но действия проводить по инициализации.

Comment: Всё ,я понял, constructor() : this(UUID.randomUUID(),null,Date(),null) {}  (пример из другой оперы но суть вроде понял)

Comment: обновил ответ для пустого конструктора

Comment: У вас пустой конструктор будет присваивать null всем полям класса,в моём варианте при вызове конструктора без параметров я двум полям ставлю определённые значения, двум другим null

Comment: Ну в котлине вам в любом случае придется либо давать null, либо не null значение дефолтное, либо инициализировать в конструкторе. В Java ведь же все значения которые не присвоины в конструкторе будут null. Других вариантов тут физически не может быть. Просто котлин вас заставляет это делать явно, вот и вся разница

Comment: Это правильный ответ, добавлю  что еще ради таких данных  использовать data классы

Answer (score 2):

В kotlin насколько я знаю делается тоже два конструктора, и вызывается тот который вам нужен. Выглядеть это будет приблизительно так:

```
class MessageEvent() {
    var pos:Int?=null
    var user:User
    var key:String?=null

    constructor(user:User, key:String) : this() { 
      this.user=user;
      this.key=key;
    }

    constructor(user:User, key:String, pos:Int) : this() { 
      this.user=user;
      this.key=key;
      this.pos=pos;
    }

}
```

и дальше вызов будет выглядеть так:

```
MessageEvent(// тут нужный вам конструктор)
```

Вроде как-то так должно быть :)